# Is it good to load data using api instead of direct fetching from database

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, rest

I'm learning Restful Api with Laravel and now I have faced this question that is it good to use retrieved json data for loading website content (asynchronous way) instead of using direct data fetching by Controllers (synchronous way) or not?

Comment: If your frontend is React or Vue, you have to use API. If it's Blade, don't use API for the data needed on the page load. If you want to get extra data without reloading the Blade page, then use API for that part only.

Comment: Since you are asking for an opinion... here are my 2 cents. Design your software in a way that PHP is your backend (Mezzio) and focus on JSON API for communication. For the frontend, pick VueJS (yes, I am still stuck on V2 since Vuetify is not ready yet for V3)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by synchronous way? if you're mentioning Laravel blade, then you mostly not needed to fetch data by calling APIs, but if the front-end stack is something like Vue or React or Angular, then as @GuidoFaecke mentioned, you have to separate the back-end and front-end cores, and then connect them by using API in an asynchronous way.